# Обновил UBUNTU с 16.04 до 18.04 версии, исчезло боковое меню

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, ubuntu-unity

**Собственно это и весь вопрос. Ниже скрин**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это же Gnome , сверху меню которое выпадет на весь экран ...

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не по теме

Comment: @МаксимЛенский смысле не по теме? что за бред

Comment: @МаксимЛенский а как вернуть обычное меню?

Comment: это не форум ubuntu и о программировании здесь ни слова т.е не по теме ресурса

Comment: @МаксимЛенский посмотрите много тем с убунтой связанных на ру стек овер флоу. Так что по теме все!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77135/discussion-between---and-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно это поможет

```
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 4):

В Ubuntu >=17.10 сменили менеджер рабочего стола с Unity на Gnome.
В любой момент Вы можете поставить тот менеджер, который Вам нравится.
Большинство оболочек являются предустановленными в разные версии Ubuntu.

### Ubuntu Unity - ubuntu < 17.10

[image: Install Unity]

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

### Gnome Shell - ubuntu >= 17.10

[image: Install GNOME Shell]

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell
```

### Xfce - xubuntu

[image: Install Xfce]

```
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop xfce4-goodies
```

### KDE - kubuntu

[image: Install KDE]

```
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

### KDE Plasma

[image: Install KDE Plasma]

```
sudo apt install plasma-desktop
```

### LXDE - lubuntu

[image: Install LXDE]

```
sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop
```

### Cinnamon - linux mint

[image: Install Cinnamon]

```
sudo apt install cinnamon-desktop-environment
```

### MATE - ubuntu mate

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

### E [Enlightenment](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Enlightenment)

```
sudo apt install e17 # old and stable version
```

или посвежее:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:niko2040/e19 && sudo apt update
sudo apt install enlightenment terminology # fresh stable e21 for now
```